# Can't get QtCreator to deploy to android emulator

Tags: android, qt, deployment, qt-creator

I'm running following setup:

Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
Qt creator 3.0.1
Qt 5.2.1
NDK r9d 64bit
adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321.zip

I managed get it compile. I started emulator before deploying the app. but instead of sending the apk to running emulator it started a new one... Qt Create went not responding for a while...new emulator got booted up and after a while Qt createor started to respond again and returned following compile output.

Also I tried to get it working on Windows 7 64bit before Ubuntu but the result was very same. Also I believe the software versions were mostly same.

```
17:11:12: Removing directory /home/rikko/android/projects/build-omgFrickingGosh-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Debug/android-build
17:11:12: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/rikko/android/projects/build-omgFrickingGosh-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Debug/android-build install
cp -f -R /home/rikko/android/projects/omgFrickingGosh/qml/omgFrickingGosh /home/rikko/android/projects/build-omgFrickingGosh-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Debug/android-build/assets/qml/
install -m 755 -p "libomgFrickingGosh.so" "/home/rikko/android/projects/build-omgFrickingGosh-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Debug/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libomgFrickingGosh.so"
17:11:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
Error while building/deploying project omgFrickingGosh (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Deploy to Android device'
17:13:26: Elapsed time: 02:14.</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually maanged to get it runningun Windows. 
Seems that most probablt the suspects are new SDK or NDK.

So the configuration that is currently working on 64bit Win 7 is followng:

```
JDK: jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe
Ant: apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.zip
NDK: android-ndk-r9-windows-x86_64.zip 
SDK: adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030.zip (contains SDK manager 22.3)
Qt 5.2.1 and QtCreator 3.0.1 both from qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.5.0-2-online.exe
```

Contact me if you have similar problem and can't get your hands on these package versions yourself.

Comment: Managed to get same configuration working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS too.